# StreamingQueryException: 'Error while Describe Streams\n=== Streaming Query

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, aws-glue

I am gettign below  error while running a Glue Streaming job which fails to connect to Kinesis data source :

Error:

```
WARNING:root:StreamingQueryException caught. Retry number 10 ERROR:root:Exceeded maximuim number of retries in streaming interval, 
exception thrown Parse yarn logs get error message:  
StreamingQueryException: 'Error while Describe Streams\n=== Streaming Query ===\nIdentifier: [id = 60exxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Following are the set of jars i used :

```
spark-tags_2.11-2.4.0.jar,
spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11-2.4.0.jar,
spark-streaming_2.11-2.4.0.jar,
aws-java-sdk-sts-1.11.271.jar,
amazon-kinesis-client-1.8.10.jar,
spark-sql_2.11-2.4.0.jar

#####################################################################

spark-tags_2.11-2.4.3.jar,
spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11-2.4.3.jar,
aws-java-sdk-sts-1.11.271.jar,
jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.6.7.jar,
unused-1.0.0.jar,
spark-sql_2.11-2.4.3.jar

##########################################
spark-sql-kinesis_2.11-1.1.3-spark_2.4.jar,
spark-tags_2.11-2.4.0.jar,
unused-1.0.0.jar,
scala-library-2.11.12.jar,
spark-sql_2.11-2.4.0.jar
```

Please suggest, since there is very less and vague information on Glue Streaming and Kinesis integration.

Answer (score 0):

Glue Streaming with Kinesis as a source uses a version of [qubole/kinesis-sql](https://github.com/qubole/kinesis-sql)
The Samples on that Github Repo should be a good starting point. Also this [blog](https://www.qubole.com/blog/kinesis-connector-for-structured-streaming/) by qubole.

Kinesis ASL ([spark-streaming-kinesis-asl](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kinesis-integration.html)) uses older spark streaming APIs, InputDStreams etc. Glue streaming has in-built support for spark structured streaming APIs and so if using Glue Streaming with Kinesis, need not import all those dependencies. If the application *has* to be Kinesis ASL based, then one might try building a Jar with all these dependencies and running them as part of a normal Glue ETL Job itself instead of a Glue Streaming Job. Porting the application to use the spark structured APIs would be much easier.

Also, there is an example of using the Structured Streaming APIs with Glue Streaming on the docs - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-etl-scala-example.html